# .NET Core 3.1 custom ClaimsPrincipal not working correctly with AddAuthenticationSchemes policy

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, authorization

My .NET Core 3.1 app has one authentication scheme (cookie authentication with OpenId Connect) and I'm planning to add another authentication scheme.

The other authentication scheme will only be allowed in one specific area, whereas the current authentication scheme should only be allowed in all other places.

To meet both requirements, I've started to create an authorization policy to authorize the authentication scheme of the user (cookie authentication for the default area).

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("X", builder => builder.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Cookies").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});

...

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization("X");
});
```

So far, so good. All endpoints will be authorized with the authentication scheme.
However, the solution also uses a custom implementation of `IClaimsTransformation` because I need to override the `User.IsInRole` logic.

This custom claims transformer is registered as follows

```cs
services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, CustomClaimsTransformer>();
```

For simplicity, the contents of the `CustomClaimsTransformer` just returns a wrapper object with additional logic

```cs
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var customPrincipal = new CustomClaimsPrincipal(principal) as ClaimsPrincipal;
    return Task.FromResult(customPrincipal);
}
```

The problem:

When I use `AddAuthenticationSchemes("Cookies")` in my authorization policy, the `TransformAsync` of my `CustomClaimsTransformer` will be called, but the `IsInRole` of my `CustomClaimsPrincipal` will never be called; meaning it fails on every `IsInRole` check.

If I leave out the `AddAuthenticationSchemes("Cookies")` part, my `IsInRole` method magically does get called again.

Is there any way I can use my `CustomClaimsPrincipal` when using a required authentication scheme in an authorization policy?

Comment: Try to change your code [like this](https://codeshare.io/j0KlLL), and tell me if it works ?

Comment: @JasonPan The property ClaimsTransformation does not exist in CookieAuthenticationOptions / AuthenticationSchemeOptions

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I have updated the code and share it below, please kindly  check it. If it still not works, could you create a brand new project( hide you sensitive info) which can reproduce the issue, I will check it. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below code, it should be work. I have tried in my side.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CustomAuthCore31
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add your custom claims transformation
            services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, CustomClaimsTransformer>();

            // Add authentication services
            services.AddAuthentication("CustomCookies")
                .AddScheme<CookieAuthenticationOptions, CustomCookieAuthenticationHandler>("CustomCookies", options => {
                    // Configure your cookie settings here
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("X", builder => builder.AddAuthenticationSchemes("CustomCookies").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            });
            ....
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization("X");
            });
        }
    }

    public class CustomCookieAuthenticationHandler : CookieAuthenticationHandler
    {
        private readonly IClaimsTransformation _claimsTransformation;

        public CustomCookieAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<CookieAuthenticationOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock,
            IClaimsTransformation claimsTransformation)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            _claimsTransformation = claimsTransformation;
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var result = await base.HandleAuthenticateAsync();
            if (result.Succeeded && result.Principal != null)
            {
                var transformedPrincipal = await _claimsTransformation.TransformAsync(result.Principal);
                return AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(transformedPrincipal, result.Ticket.Properties, result.Ticket.AuthenticationScheme));
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class CustomClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            var customPrincipal = new CustomClaimsPrincipal(principal);
            return Task.FromResult(customPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal);
        }
    }

    public class CustomClaimsPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
    {
        public CustomClaimsPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal principal) : base(principal)
        {
        }
        // Your custom logic for IsInRole, etc.
        public override bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            // Your custom logic here.
            return base.IsInRole(role);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The line "var result = await base.HandleAuthenticateAsync();" throws a NullReferenceException

Comment: Hi @Randy, could you create a brand new sample project without any sensitive information which can reproduce the issue, and I am willing help you to check the issue next Monday, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Hello. I did create a new .NET Core 3.1 project and replaced the startup code using your provided code, but I still received that exception.

Comment: Hi @Randy, could you hide the sensitive info and share the brand new project for me, I will check it tomorrow. And you also could leave the details about how to reproduce the issue and your requirement in readme.txt, thanks.